# Change data type to date through a query in MS Access?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I have a .csv export of data where there's something "wrong" with how MS Access sees it when it's a linked data source. MS Access refuses to see them as date fields, and gives me a #NUM! error if I try to force it. However if I import it as a regular table or open it in MS Excel, the date field works fine. As such my date fields are stuck as short text fields in the linked .csv, which prevents me from sorting by a date range.

Is it possible to use a query to change the data type of a field? Short text field goes in one side, date/time (as recognized by MS Access) comes out the other?

Comment: Try CDate() function in query.

Comment: Thank you, that was the function I needed!